# R gamsel for generalized additive model - interpretation

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I have set up a gamsel like this ( X has ~ 60 different independent variables). I am struggling to interpret the summary and plots:

```
gamsel.out <- gamsel(X,y, bases = bases, family = "binomial")
summary(gamsel.out)
```

[image]

```
gamsel.cv <- cv.gamsel(X,y,bases = bases, family = "binomial)

plot(gamsel.cv)
```

[image]

Can anyone help me in understanding what those plots show? The documentation is not enough unfortunately.

This is my gamsel.out:

```
    Call:  gamsel(x = X, y = y, family = "binomial", bases = bases) 

      NonZero Lin NonLin    %Dev Lambda
 [1,]       0   0      0 0.00000 24.550
 [2,]       1   1      0 0.03853 23.090
 [3,]       1   1      0 0.06882 21.720
 [4,]       1   1      0 0.09391 20.430
 [5,]       1   1      0 0.11490 19.220
 [6,]       1   1      0 0.13300 18.080
 [7,]       1   1      0 0.14890 17.010
 [8,]       1   1      0 0.16300 16.000
 [9,]       1   1      0 0.17550 15.050
[10,]       1   1      0 0.18680 14.160
[11,]       1   1      0 0.19690 13.320
[12,]       1   1      0 0.20610 12.530
[13,]       1   1      0 0.21440 11.790
[14,]       2   2      0 0.22560 11.090
[15,]       2   2      0 0.23560 10.430
[16,]       2   2      0 0.24510  9.811
[17,]       2   2      0 0.25370  9.229
[18,]       2   2      0 0.26180  8.682
[19,]       2   2      0 0.26930  8.167
[20,]       2   2      0 0.27640  7.683
[21,]       3   3      0 0.28410  7.227
[22,]       4   4      0 0.29240  6.799
[23,]       4   4      0 0.29990  6.395
[24,]       5   5      0 0.30720  6.016
[25,]       5   5      0 0.31470  5.659
[26,]       5   5      0 0.32180  5.324
[27,]       6   6      0 0.32860  5.008
[28,]       6   6      0 0.33500  4.711
[29,]       7   7      0 0.34110  4.432
[30,]       7   7      0 0.34720  4.169
[31,]       7   7      0 0.35280  3.922
[32,]       7   7      0 0.35810  3.689
[33,]       8   8      0 0.36360  3.470
[34,]       8   8      0 0.36930  3.264
[35,]      10  10      0 0.37480  3.071
[36,]      10  10      0 0.38000  2.889
[37,]      11  11      0 0.38500  2.717
[38,]      11  11      0 0.38980  2.556
[39,]      11  11      0 0.39420  2.405
[40,]      11  11      0 0.39850  2.262
[41,]      12  12      1 0.40300  2.128
[42,]      12  12      1 0.40730  2.002
[43,]      12  12      1 0.41120  1.883
[44,]      12  12      1 0.41470  1.771
[45,]      13  13      1 0.41800  1.666
[46,]      13  13      1 0.42130  1.567
[47,]      16  16      1 0.42500  1.474
[48,]      16  16      1 0.42880  1.387
[49,]      16  16      1 0.43210  1.305
[50,]      16  16      1 0.43530  1.227
```

And this my gamsel.cv (cross validation):

```
 $lambda.min
[1] 1.227366

$lambda.1se
[1] 1.666219

$index.min
[1] 50

$index.1se
[1] 45

attr(,"class")
[1] "cv.gamsel"
```

Comment: Is this R package [gamsel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamsel/index.html) ? Please edit your post to include calls like `library(gamsel)` when using non-base packages!

Comment: Can [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/an-unofficial-vignette-for-the-gamsel-package/) help?